# Polling byte / large messages from ActiveMQ Artemis using Apache Camel ConsumerTemplate

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-artemis, camel-jms

I'm struggling with a problem in an application based on Apache Camel when connecting to ActiveMQ Artemis via JMS. At the end of one of the Camel routes, messages are stored in an Artemis JMS queue. A legacy component running in the same application picks them up from there periodically using a `ConsumerTemplate`.

This works fine for Camel messages with plain text bodies, but causes errors when using byte array bodies: It seems Artemis treats any message with byte body as a ["large  message", which are streamed instead of kept in memory](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html). Receiving via the `ConsumerTemplate` works, but as soon as the body or headers are accessed, an exception as follows is raised:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: Failed to extract body due to: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: AMQ119023: The large message lost connection with its session, either because of a rollback or a closed session. Message: ActiveMQMessage[ID:90c4d1d5-3233-11ea-b0cc-44032c68a56f]:PERSISTENT/ClientLargeMessageImpl[messageID=2974, durable=true, address=mytest,userID=90c4d1d5-3233-11ea-b0cc-44032c68a56f,properties=TypedProperties[firedTime=Wed Jan 08 17:26:03 CET 2020,__AMQ_CID=90b4f34e-3233-11ea-b0cc-44032c68a56f,breadcrumbId=ID-NB045-evolit-co-at-1578500762151-0-1,_AMQ_ROUTING_TYPE=1,_AMQ_LARGE_SIZE=3]]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractBodyFromJms(JmsBinding.java:172) ~[camel-jms-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.createBody(JmsMessage.java:221) ~[camel-jms-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:54) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.example.cdi.JmsPoller.someMethod(JmsPoller.java:36) ~[classes/:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:481) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:300) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:273) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.AbstractBeanProcessor.process(AbstractBeanProcessor.java:188) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:53) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProducer.process(BeanProducer.java:41) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148) ~[camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer.sendTimerExchange(TimerConsumer.java:197) [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.timer.TimerConsumer$1.run(TimerConsumer.java:79) [camel-core-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555) [?:1.8.0_171]
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505) [?:1.8.0_171]
Caused by: javax.jms.IllegalStateException: AMQ119023: The large message lost connection with its session, either because of a rollback or a closed session
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl.saveBuffer(LargeMessageControllerImpl.java:273) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientLargeMessageImpl.saveToOutputStream(ClientLargeMessageImpl.java:115) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.saveToOutputStream(ActiveMQMessage.java:853) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.setObjectProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:693) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createByteArrayFromBytesMessage(JmsBinding.java:251) ~[camel-jms-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractBodyFromJms(JmsBinding.java:163) ~[camel-jms-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQIllegalStateException: AMQ119023: The large message lost connection with its session, either because of a rollback or a closed session
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.LargeMessageControllerImpl.saveBuffer(LargeMessageControllerImpl.java:273) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientLargeMessageImpl.saveToOutputStream(ClientLargeMessageImpl.java:115) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.saveToOutputStream(ActiveMQMessage.java:853) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQMessage.setObjectProperty(ActiveMQMessage.java:693) ~[artemis-jms-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.createByteArrayFromBytesMessage(JmsBinding.java:251) ~[camel-jms-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.extractBodyFromJms(JmsBinding.java:163) ~[camel-jms-2.22.1.jar:2.22.1]
        ... 21 more
```

The problem also occurs for messages that do not exceed the `minLargeMessageSize` of Artemis, in a test program even for 3 bytes.

Coincidentally, the same problem occurred in a standalone application used for testing the application. There, I was able to solve the issue by keeping the JMS session and receiver open until the JMS message body and headers were completely read. With Camel, that's abstracted away in the Spring `JmsTemplate` that Camel is based on.

---

I consulted the [user documentation of the Camel JMS component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/jms-component.html) to find configuration options that might help me. I've tried the following:

- `eagerLoadingOfProperties=true` on consumer side: no effect, only seems to affect `MessageListenerContainer`. The documentation says:

> It uses [...] Spring’s JmsTemplate for sending and a MessageListenerContainer for consuming.

However, while debugging it seemed that `MessageListenerContainer` is only used when consuming messages from an JMS endpoint in a Camel route. Using a `ConsumerTemplate` like in my case uses a `JmsTemplate` for consuming.

- `messageConverter` and `mapJmsMessage` on consumer side: no effect, they are executed when the session has already been closed
- `alwaysCopyMessage` on producer side: I thought maybe copying prevents use of streamed large messages, no effect
- `streamMessageTypeEnabled=false` on producer side: no effect
- `jmsMessageType=Bytes` on both producer and consumer side: no effect
- `transferExchange=true` on both producer and consumer side: this does seem to solve my specific case, but it feels like a workaround. Documentation advises to use the option with caution.

So right now, `transferExchange` seems to be my best bet, assuming it really solves my issue in all test cases. Nevertheless, I'd be glad to get better understanding on the issue or different solutions:

1. Why does Artemis treat small byte array messages as large messages anyway?
2. Does Camel ConsumerTemplate support streamed large messages at all?

My versions are Camel 2.22.1 and Artemis 2.10.1.

---

I've been able to reproduce my problem by modifying the Camel Example `camel-example-cdi` from the release package of Camel to have the minimal classes shown below.
In addition I've added `camel-jms` and Artemis dependencies and started Artemis locally, both like described in the `camel-example-artemis-large-messages` example.

```java
public class MyRoutes extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        setupJmsComponent();

        from("timer:writeTimer?period=6000")
                .log("writing to JMS")
                .setBody(() -> new byte[]{0,1,2})
                .to(JmsPoller.ENDPOINT);

        from("timer:pollTimer?period=3000")
            .to("bean:jmsPoller");
    }

    private void setupJmsComponent() {
        ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
        JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
        jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        getContext().addComponent("jms", jmsComponent);
    }

}
```

```java
@Singleton
@Named("jmsPoller")
public class JmsPoller {
    static final String ENDPOINT = "jms:queue:mytest";

    @Inject
    private ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate;

    public void someMethod(String body) {
        Exchange exchange = consumerTemplate.receive(ENDPOINT, 1000L);
        System.out.println("Received " + (exchange == null ? null : exchange.getIn().getBody()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted?

Comment: No, unfortunately I never had time to investigate this further than the workaround of using Byte[] body.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ Artemis doesn't treat just *any* message with a byte body as a "large" message. It's worth noting that the broker ultimately treats all message bodies as an array of bytes because that's exactly what they are. However, in order to be considered "large" the message has to exceed a certain size. [The documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html) states:

> Any message larger than a certain size is considered a large message. Large messages will be split up and sent in fragments. This is determined by the URL parameter `minLargeMessageSize`.
>
> > **Note**:
> >
> > Apache ActiveMQ Artemis messages are encoded using 2 bytes per character so if the message data is filled with ASCII characters (which are 1 byte) the size of the resulting Apache ActiveMQ Artemis message would roughly double. This is important when calculating the size of a "large" message as it may appear to be less than the `minLargeMessageSize` before it is sent, but it then turns into a "large" message once it is encoded.
>
> The default value is 100KiB.

It looks like the application's use-case simply doesn't fit with the semantics of large message support in ActiveMQ Artemis since the session which the message came from is being closed before the message's body is fully received.

Therefore, I recommend that you either keep the session open until the body is read or increase the `minLargeMessageSize` on the URL of the application which is *sending* the message so that no messages are ever considered "large." The latter option may result in greater memory usage on the broker since the entire message body will be held in memory at once.

Comment: I agree that it seems like the Apache Camel abstraction used for receiving messages doesn't seem to fit large message support. 

However, my minimal test case sends a message with only 3 bytes body via Camel, and that exact three bytes end up in a file in `data/large-messages` of my Artemis broker. I don't understand why that is treated as a large-message and have also tried raising the limit using `minLargeMessageSize`.

Comment: I just found out that using a `Byte[]` body instead of `byte[]` on the Camel message causes them to be treated as regular messages, not as large messages. I'll continue testing and provide the answer if it works.

Comment: I'm very curious to know why that actually makes a difference. Can you drill into the Camel code to see what's actually going on? Does the Camel code treat these cases differently or does it pass through untouched to the Artemis JMS client?